# FAB not moving down on Snackbar dismiss

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

On my phone and that of a friend, the FAB in the default Android Studio Activity does not move down after the Snackbar dismisses.

On the emulator and a few other friends' phones, it does animate down.

The first friend and I have changed animation scale to 0.5, but setting it to 1.0 and rebooting hasn't fixed the issue.

This should have been fixed in Design Support Library 23.2.0, and I am using 23.3.0, as the example comes with that set.

Edit:
The layout and code for completion purposes:

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.bas.test.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.bas.test.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_open_black_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        if (fab != null) {
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "You clicked the FAB!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Change bar text", mOnClickListener).show();
                }
            });
        }

        mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Changed!");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your layout code. And also post the snackbar implementation.

Comment: It's the default Basic Activity, but let me update it.

Comment: Have you tried with [23.4.0](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/B7QhFkWZ6YX)? It had [a fix](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206416) for FAB positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @ianhanniballake, this was fixed in [Design Support Library 23.4.0](https://plus.google.com/b/108072528500384398522/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/B7QhFkWZ6YX).

Comment: What? Can you explain? I can't accept the answer yet, no other was provided.

Comment: Actually my bad. I missed you are the OP and that's changes things a bit

Comment: I thought so. No problem! :)

Comment: Is it still working ? I've the last update of support design library, and it doesn't work :/

Comment: This was for a project and I haven't checked in a long time, but I can update my stuff and take a look if you want.